# How to pass the List<String> value as String to the Other function

Tags: c#, while-loop

I have a `List<>` as lsSplitMember I am sending it through the while loop to the function
as a string.But it throws exception message "`Index was out of range`. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection".
I have tried with the below code .

```
//Globally declared variable lsSplitMember
List<String> lsSplitMember=new List<String>();



int ic = lsSplitMember.Count();
while (ic != 0)
{
  Process_Split(lsSplitMember[ic]);
  ic--;
}


Protected void Process_Split(String Member)
{
 //Some Code
}
```

So how can I Solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
int ic = lsSplitMember.Count();
while (ic != 0)
{
  Process_Split(lsSplitMember[ic-1]); // your index was off-by-one
  ic--;
}
```

Please note that using the C# language features, that's a lot of unnecessary meta-code:

```
foreach(var text in lsSplitMember)
{
  Process_Split(text);
}
```

This is a lot easier to read and way less error prone to write. If you need the list to be processes upside down, you can reverse it first.

Answer (score 1):

The count is one greater than the last index of the `List` since they are zero-indexed, and this is the index you try to access. Really, you should use an iterator for this:

```
foreach( string s in lsSplitMember )
    Process_Split( s );
```

Comment: ... unless it's important for the strings to be processed last-to-first.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

Change `Process_Split(lsSplitMember[ic]);` to `Process_Split(lsSplitMember[ic-1]);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
List<String> lsSplitMember=new List<String>();



int ic = lsSplitMember.Count();
while (ic != 0)
{
  ic--;
  Process_Split(lsSplitMember[ic]);

}


Protected void Process_Split(String Member)
{
 //Some Code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lsSplitMember.ForEach(s =>
{
    Process_Split(s);
});
```

Provided lsSplitMember is not null